# Visual Studio 2017 Project Configuration Properties > Driver Install > Package Files. does not exist

Tags: visual-studio-2017, wdk

I'm trying to build [XPSDrvSmpl](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/print/XPSDrvSmpl#build-the-sample) Microsoft/Windows-Driver-Samples. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and WDK for Windows 10, version 1709.

In the readme.md Build the sample block it says:  In the Solution Explorer, right click the Package project and select Properties. c. In the left pane, click Configuration Properties > Driver Install > Package Files. But In the driver install there is no Package Files appears.

Is it because of Visual Studio 2017/WDK or is there another reason for that?

Answer (score -1):

Change your configuration to Active, instead of All Configurations. (In the window where Driver Install > Package Files is)

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to bother with these steps, they aren't actually necessary at all to test our your driver (including debugging it) and in my experience more people than not fail to work these features properly except Microsoft themselves.

Right click the Driver Package project in the Solution Explorer and select the Unload Project option.

Now build your device driver once your configuration settings have been applied appropriately. Afterwards, copy the compiled binary (and if required the *.INF) to the test machine. Shared folders across a network/VM are commonly used to make this a lot simpler. You can still use Visual Studio for remote kernel debugging and stepping through your driver, or standalone WinDbg.